# Verification: DFA/NFA that accepts all strings over $\{0,1\}$ with exactly one block of $00$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata

I am trying to design a DFA or NFA that accepts all strings over $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$ in which the block $00$ appears only once.

Here is what I've tried. 
[image: diagram of possible NFA accepting language]

Can you verify that this accepts all string over $\{0,1\}$ that has exactly one block of $00$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you constructed your NFA correctly. Note that to convert your NFA to a DFA, you can simply remove the loop transition $\delta(q_3,1)=q_3$, include the loop transition $\delta(q_4, 1) = q_4$, and draw an extra circle around $q_4$ in order to include it in your set $F$ of final/accept states.

Comment: I see. Wouldnt I also need a self loop on q4 if it is a 1? Consider 0011 for example.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.